Public Key Calculation in LMS
In RFC 8554 "Leighton-Micali Hash-Based Signatures", in section 4.3, the generation of the public key is described. The iterative hash function inputs is $I \| u32str(q) \| u16str(i) \| u8str(j) \| tmp$, where $tmp$ is the iterative element with initial value $x[i]$, the private key associated with this public key.
What is the motivation to use $I, q, i,$ and $j$ as inputs to the hash function? $I, q$ and $i$ are all constants, so seemingly do not contribute to the entropy, nor to the uniqueness. It is required that the initial value of "$tmp$" will be unique, and if the procedure suggested in the standard to generate it is used, it already includes the values of $I, q$ and $i$, so they seems redundant. The only changing value is 8 bits of the iteration index $j$, and in the best case it adds 8 bit to the entropy of the input, if it was random (its a counter).
So, why not do simply $tmp=H(tmp)$ instead the above formula?


What is the motivation to use $I, q, i,$ and $j$ as inputs to the hash function? 
So, why not do simply $tmp=H(tmp)$ instead the above formula?

Because just doing $tmp=H(tmp)$ would make the system weaker.
Remember, the attack gains an advantage if he finds a preimage to the value within the signature, which is computed using the above formula.  If we were talking about a single hash, you would be correct.  However, LMS uses lots of hashes of this form, both within a single signature, across several signatures, and across signatures signed by different keys.
So, what an attacker could do is collect a number of such hashes (each of which would give him an advantage if he finds a preimage), and then pick an arbitrary hash value, hash it, and see if that value matches any of the hashes he has collected - if it does, he has found a preimage to one of the hashes, which gives him an advantage.
If he can collect (over a series of signatures, and possibly over several different public keys) $2^{20}$ such preimages, this effectively reduces the security from $256$ bits to $236$ bits - no one could say that this would be a practical break of the system, but still, it's more than we would like.
By including $I, q, i$ into the hash, we prevent this multitarget attack; when generating a preimage, the attacker must insert values for $I, q, i$; this means that the resulting hash must match the same internal hash that used the same $I, q, i$ values, which means that it must be in a specific location for a specific public key.
The reason for the $j$ is a bit more subtle; it is there to prevent an attack where the attacker iteratively computes $tmp=H(I,q,i,tmp)$ and sees if it eventually results in the top public value.  It turns out this attack would knock off a few bits of security; including the $j$ value prevents this as well.
